# Is there any software for share desktop can be as simple as one click?

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm working as an IT support in a hospital with big building, IT department is on floor 11(total 16),
We need to deal with all kinds of software problem, and our elevators are really really slow,
so remote desktop sharing is the time saver(and knee saver).

These are the requirements:

- Support windows XP.
- Our client aren't good at computer, so the software should as simple as "click the icon on the desktop then tell me the number".
- PC are all connected to local network.
- No budget. we are in China, no available payment method.

Teamviewer can one click share, feature is good, but not in local network.

Comment: If its a reasonably fast local network, why not VNC? In addition what OS/version do you use?

Comment: What is with the Remote Desktop Connection available in Windows 7 and Windows 8 by default ? Or Windows Remote Assistance ?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek vnc is a good solution, but I didn't find a "one click" solution.

Comment: @Devid we are windows XP, and no plan to upgrade("lots of old PC")

Comment: How hard have you looked? http://www.uvnc.com/products/uvnc-sc.html looks promising for your needs, tho naturally you need to test it.

Comment: I like Dameware for my IT job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @Journeyman Geek 's comment, I've tried uvnc-sc: http://www.uvnc.com/products/uvnc-sc.html

It has one server exe file(winvnc), When the first time it is opened, it requires some configuration, then it will create a ini config file(UltraVNC.ini). 
After that, each open will require no more config. it is exactly the tool I need.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to go for teamviewer. This software is one click away! when you install the software you can assign a password and an ID. The user only has to start the application using the desktop icon. The software then activates it self. you can use another instance in your pc , type the pre configure id and password to login to the pc. Nothing else!

Comment: I have mentioned that, we are in local network, this function does not work.

Comment: @linjunhalida Teamviewer can still work on a LAN only connection, you must connect using IP numbers instead of Teamviewer ID'. The IP number is displayed on screen in the Qucksupport client when it can't connect to the internet.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Tried, without network connection, TeamViewer quick support cannot setup ID and password.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Remote Assistance is worth a try

- http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457004.aspx